# Where are GCC's token types defined?

Tags: gcc

I'm reading GCC's source code, but I can't find in which file are the token types defined, for example, `CPP_NAME`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Token types are in libcpp/include/cpplib.h (`TTYPE_TABLE`), keywords in gcc/c-family/c-common.h (`enum rid`).

Comment: Thank you. I had tried to grep with keyword 'CPP_NAME' but got nothing. They are defined by macro concatenation, no wonder I couldn't find it.

Comment: Yes, in general you should watch out for std. prefixes, these tend to be appended inside macro so you won't be able to grep them.